# Update specific row in Smartsheet C# SDK

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

I have a column with a system row number feature which I have imported into SQL. I have made changes to the row in SQL, and now want to update it back onto smartsheet.

How do I reference the row on Smartsheet, via the system number column? See https://www.smartsheet.com/blog/support-tip-system-columns

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the Row Id, which is the only persistent identifier for a row.
Then you can perform updates with `PUT /sheets/{sheetId}/rows`

Comment: Sorry Steve, would you care to elaborate a little?

Comment: Your original question isn't really clear. The system columns are not relevant and perhaps are distracting you. When you read from a sheet it is critical that you retain the Row Id. When you want to update the sheet later, you must specify the Row Id so we know where to save the data. See the documentation for Update Row (http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#update-row-s). It may be clearer to look at the CURL example first, since the C# builder syntax can be tricky. In C#, the Row Id is passed to Row.UpdateRowBuilder()

Comment: Please take a look at the sample project here: https://github.com/smartsheet-samples/csharp-read-write-sheet